# Batch file that asks for user name and performs processes

Tags: batch-file, permissions

I work in IT in a GIS group (mapping). We have a server with folders for all of our GIS users. Whenever a new GIS-using co-worker is identified, because GIS data can be HUGE, they are given READ access to ALL folders on that server and a new folder just for them is created and they are given WRITE access to it.

I would like to create a batch process that would ask for a username, then give that username READ access to all folders, ask for a foldername and create that folder and give that username WRITE access to that folder.

How would I do this?

Comment: You'll be using `set /p` to prompt for input, `mkdir` to create a directory, and icacls.exe to set permissions.

Comment: If user name is identical to user account name, you can omit `set /p` and use instead environment variable __USERNAME__, see [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 1):

That what you are trying to do is an login script.

I have wrote an example with 3 users:

```
@echo off

:start

  set /p username=Insert Username: 

  if /i "%username%"=="User1" goto User1
  if /i "%username%"=="User2" goto User2
  if /i "%username%"=="User3" goto User3
  goto start


:User1

  set /p folder1=Insert Foldername:

  mkdir %folder1%

  goto stop


:User2

  set /p folder2=Insert Foldername:

  mkdir %folder2%

  goto stop


:User3

  set /p folder3=Insert Foldername:

  mkdir %folder3%

  goto stop


:stop

 cls
 exit
```

The permissions are allowed by default.

I hope I was able to help you.